# Sum values pairwise in a python list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Say that I have a list:

```
alist = [1, 3, -5, 4, 2, -1]
```

How would you change each value in the list by adding the next value to it? So, for example, the first value becomes 4, second value becomes -2, etc...

I was thinking to use `for number in alist: number = number + # what next?`.

How would I do it?

Comment: What happens to the last number?

Answer (score 6):

First of all, what you have is a [tuple](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), not a list. Tuples are immutable, which means that you cannot reassign their elements

Here is a way to create a new list, without altering the original:

```
>>> alist
[1, 3, -5, 4, 2, -1]
>>> [i+j for i,j in zip(alist, alist[1:])]
[4, -2, -1, 6, 1]
```

Note that you end up with one less element, as the last element in the list is not considered

Here is a way to do it, by altering the original (no new list is created):

```
for i in range(len(alist)-1):
    alist[i] += alist[i+1]
```

Note that the last element in the list is untouched.

Comment: You are making some assumptions here.

Comment: @Julio: yes. But to some extent, that really can't be helped, as the question is under-specified

Comment: Understandably so :) now at least your updated answer has more context.

Answer (score 0):

This will drop the last element, since there is no "next" for the last one:

```
>>> alist = (1, 3, -5, 4, 2, -1)
>>> newlist = [a + b for a, b in zip(alist, alist[1:])]
>>> newlist
[4, -2, -1, 6, 1]
```

Alternatively, [`zip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) ([`izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) in python 2) will keep it:

```
import itertools
>>> newlist = [a + b for a, b in itertools.zip_longest(alist, alist[1:], fillvalue=0)]
>>> newlist
[4, -2, -1, 6, 1, -1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way:

```
[alist[i] + alist[i+1] for i in range(len(alist)-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the fans of maps and lambdas:

```
map(lambda x: sum(x), zip(alist, alist[1:]))
```

or simply

```
map(sum, zip(alist, alist[1:]))
```

Comment: @mhlester Ah, just realized this - was editing while you commented :)

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

alist = [1, 3, -5, 4, 2, -1]
new_alist = [a+b for a,b in pairwise(alist)]        # => [4, -2, -1, 6, 1]
```